# Disable TabView animation on Tab click event?

Tags: flutter

How can I disable `TabView` animation when `Tab` in `TabBar` clicked ?
I added

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

for TabView but that doesn't apply for TabBar.

I'm using `DefaultTabController`.

Comment: One year passed, no one can solve this problem, and the Flutter team do not provide the interface to disable the animation

Answer (score 1):

Based on [a very good answer on github about this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16474#issuecomment-603977105), which achieves something similar to what your looking for (but with a `bottomNavigationBar`) here I share with you another workaround. It consists of combining a `DefaultTabController` with a `PageView`, a `PageController` and a simple index. Try this out.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tabs with no animation',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  PageController _pageController;
  final int currentTab = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: currentTab);
    super.initState();
  }

  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'One'),
    Tab(
      text: 'Two',
    ),
  ];

  var tabs = [
    TabOne(),
    TabTwo(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var pageView = PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      children: tabs,
    );

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: myTabs.length,
      child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                ),
                width: 200,
                height: 50,
                child: TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
                  },
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      color: Colors.black),
                  tabs: myTabs,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: pageView),
    );
  }
}

class TabOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabOne({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('Tab one')),
    );
  }
}

class TabTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabTwo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('Tab two')),
    );
  }
}
```

Doing so, you have a something identical to a `TabBarView` but without animation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this can be achieved using DefaultTabController easily as of 2022.

Here is my solution to this:

```
class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // when initializing the `TabController` set `animationDuration` as `zero`.
    _tabController =
        TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, animationDuration: Duration.zero);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: ColorPalette.white,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController, // set the tab controller of your `TabBar`
                enableFeedback: false,
                onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                tabs: [
                  TabItem(
                      selectedIndex: _tabController.index,
                      index: 0,
                      assetName: Assets.tabHome),
                  TabItem(
                      selectedIndex: _tabController.index,
                      index: 1,
                      assetName: Assets.tabCare),
                  TabItem(
                      selectedIndex: _tabController.index,
                      index: 2,
                      assetName: Assets.tabProfile),
                ],
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController, // set the controller of your `TabBarView`
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  children: const [
                    ParentHomePage(),
                    ParentCarePage(),
                    ParentAccountPage()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is animationDuration allowed in TabController's constructor?

Comment: set animationDuration to be Zero and check

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to disable the transition animation on `TabBarView`. As a workaround, you can use a `Container` that'll return different pages depending on the tab selected.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
  }

  var _homeScaffoldKey = Key("Scaffold Key");
  var tabController;
  var currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _homeScaffoldKey,
      body: _getCustomContainer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Material(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: new TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          indicatorColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 25, 255, 0.0),
          controller: tabController,
          onTap: (value) {
            setState(() {
              currentPage = value;
            });
          },
          tabs: <Widget>[
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.accessibility),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _getCustomContainer() {
    switch (currentPage) {
      case 0:
        return page1();
      case 1:
        return page2();
      case 2:
        return page3();
      case 3:
        return page4();
    }
  }

  page1() => Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page 1"),
        ),
      );
  page2() => Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page 2"),
        ),
      );
  page3() => Container(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page 3"),
        ),
      );
  page4() => Container(
        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page 4"),
        ),
      );
}
```

Demo

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

```
DefaultTabController(
              animationDuration: Duration.zero)
```

Comment: Please add some details, code-only answers are difficult to understand

Answer (score -5):

You can fix it by going to MaterialApp and typing

```
theme:new ThemeData(
splashColor:Colors.blue,
highlightColor: Colors.blue
)
```

What it means if your tab background color blue you will change splashColor and highlightColor to blue that means the animation isn't disabled, but it doesn't appear because the animation splashcolor and highlight will be blue such as Tab Background.