# Disable animation when changing tabs in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a tabbar with 3 tabs in flutter. When changing from first tab to the third tab also the initState method of tab2 is called. I don't want that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When on tab1 and click on tab3 I want that tab3 is displayed immediately. Without animation.

Comment: Too broad. Could you share more details and some code?

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to do this? This post comes up as the first result on Google for me.

Answer (score 17):

Disable animation between flutter tabs by setting animation duration to zero like this

```
    tabController = TabController(
    animationDuration: Duration.zero);
```

Thank me later!

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: it Works fine. I'll thank you now. Note: this is TabController, not DefaultTabController.

Comment: For DefaultTabController use `animationDuraion` property.
So it will be:
`DefaultTabController(
      animationDuration: Duration.zero (...) 
)`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you could try setting a custom `TabController` to the `TabBar` and `TabBarView`, which overrides the `animateTo` method such that the animation is skipped:

```
class CustomTabController extends TabController {
  @override
  void animateTo(int value, {Duration duration = kTabScrollDuration, Curve curve = Curves.ease}) {
    super.animateTo(value, duration: null, curve: null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. `animateTo` of the custom controller is called but it antimates even if I put 'index = value' into it.

Comment: `_tabController.animateTo(_selectedIndex, duration: null);` this works

Answer (score 0):

Based on [a very good answer on github about this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16474#issuecomment-603977105), which achieves something similar to what your looking for (but with a `bottomNavigationBar`) [here I share with you an answer of mine with another workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608028/13766744) It consists of combining a `DefaultTabController` with a `PageView`, a `PageController` and a simple index.

Answer (score -1):

This is no animation TabController code.
Please try it.

```
class NoAnimationTabController extends TabController {
  NoAnimationTabController(
      {int initialIndex = 0,
      @required int length,
      @required TickerProvider vsync})
      : super(initialIndex: initialIndex, length: length, vsync: vsync);

  @override
  void animateTo(int value,
      {Duration duration = kTabScrollDuration, Curve curve = Curves.ease}) {
    super.animateTo(value,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 0), curve: curve);
  }
}
```